# Issue with a simple joomla form

Tags: web-applications, joomla, joomla-extensions

I need someone who could help me do a small task of creating an 'upload document' field in my joomla form.

The data together with the uploaded document will be sent to an email. The form is working nice otherwise.

I have no experience in joomla. I am a mobile app developer. Please be a little easy :)

Comment: Hi, fair enough if you're new to Joomla. I can understand that, however it's always best to show that you have attempted something yourself with some code snippets. I see that you're using the standard Joomla contact form, so what I suggest is you do is look at the [Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms) and [Contact Forms](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/contact-forms) categories on the Joomla Extensions Directory so see if there is anything that will suit your need and save you any coding work ;)

Comment: editing core Joomla files is never recommended for multiple reasons. Template overrides can be made but this is only for styling and in your case extra functionality is needed, so as stated before, an extension is your best and easiest bet

Comment: @Lodder Yeah I did use an extension RSForm to create the form I need. How do I replace the existing form with my new form in the contact page? I don't see the code and that's troubling me :(

Comment: In the Joomla backend, go to the Menu Manager and open the "contact" menu item that you created. Then click **select** next to **Menu Item Type** and find the RSForms extension in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best thing to use in Joomla for forms is made by a company called RSJOOMLA. The product you want is RSFORMS!PRO.

http://www.rsjoomla.com/joomla-extensions/joomla-form.html

Comment: Yeah if you see the above comment I did use RSForm pro and it's quite good too.